# Javascript: Convert date string to epoch

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this string: `Wed Jun 17 2020 14:57:34 GMT-0500`

How can I turn to epoch?

Using Moment.js is fine.

Answer (score 1):

`(new Date('Wed Jun 17 2020 14:57:34 GMT-0500')).getTime()`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let date = new Date('Wed Jun 17 2020 14:57:34 GMT-0500')
let epoch = Number(date)
console.log(epoch)
```

If you convert a JS date object to a number the number is the epoch time (in milliseconds).

> Note: This only works if Javascript can parse the date string correctly (It appears to be able to for your example)

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you should do smth like

```
(new Date('Wed Jun 17 2020 14:57:34 GMT-0500')).getTime() / 1000
```

since `getTime` returnы time in milliseconds however [epoch](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) should be in seconds

Comment: Сергей, слава Украине!

Comment: Героям слава, как говорится. Хотя к теме вопроса это не имеет отношения ))